# Almost-Vandermonde Determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, terminology

While going through an exercise, I ended up proving the result for the determinant of this 'Vandermonde-like' matrix for $n \geq 2, \ k \geq n-1$:

$$\det\begin{pmatrix}1& a_1 & \cdots & a_1^{n-1}& a_1^k\\
1& a_2 & \cdots & a_2^{n-1}& a_2^k\\
\vdots &\vdots &  & \vdots & \vdots\\
1& a_n & \cdots & a_n^{n-1}& a_n^k
\end{pmatrix}=\prod_{i > j}(x_{i}-x_{j})\sum_{\alpha_{1}+...+\alpha_{n} = k-n+1}(x_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}...x_{n}^{\alpha_{n}})$$

What I would like to know if it has any special name, or where I can find other cool variants of the Vandermonde matrix.

Comment: This is a particular case of an alternant. See [John R. Stembridge, *A Concise Proof of the Littlewood-Richardson Rule*, Electronic Journal of Combinatorics **9** (2002) #5](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v9i1n5/) for the general case (and much more). In Stembridge's notation, your determinant is $a_\lambda$ for $\lambda = \left(k-n+1,0,0,\ldots,0\right)$ (up to permutation of columns).

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to read about it right away!

Comment: It's a very worthwhile read; 3 pages, almost entirely self-contained (you only need to know the classical Vandermonde determinant), and proves several crucial results in algebraic combinatorics.

Comment: A particular case, with an answer by... darij grinberg : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3024496

Comment: Take a look at the recent very interesting PhD thesis : http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1073960/FULLTEXT02